# Constant errors when installing ccxt module in python

Tags: python, pip, ccxt

New to python but not to coding and just getting to grips with installing modules. Seem to get pretty far when installing ccxt with **py -m pip install ccxt** except it keeps throwing an error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'C:\Users\samib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\samib\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7wa5a9m4\\pycares_61a5dda285624907b00263dfe14e0ed6\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\samib\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7wa5a9m4\\pycares_61a5dda285624907b00263dfe14e0ed6\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\samib\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-yolmpi02\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\samib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Include\pycares'
     cwd: C:\Users\samib\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7wa5a9m4\pycares_61a5dda285624907b00263dfe14e0ed6\
Complete output (17 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pycares
copying src\pycares\errno.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pycares
copying src\pycares\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pycares
copying src\pycares\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pycares
copying src\pycares\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pycares
copying src\pycares\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pycares
running build_ext
generating cffi module 'build\\temp.win-amd64-3.9\\Release\\_cares.c'
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
building '_cares' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\samib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\samib\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7wa5a9m4\\pycares_61a5dda285624907b00263dfe14e0ed6\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\samib\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7wa5a9m4\\pycares_61a5dda285624907b00263dfe14e0ed6\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\samib\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-yolmpi02\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\samib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Include\pycares' Check the logs for full command output.
```

is anyone one with the machines and able to help me decipher this and hopefully help me fix the ish?

also getting this issue in the IDLE. my code reads **import ccxt, print(ccxt.exchanges)** and this is all im getting back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/samib/Documents/arbbot.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ccxt import ccxt
  File "C:/Users/samib/Documents\ccxt\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from ccxt.base.exchange import Exchange                     # noqa: F401
  File "C:/Users/samib/Documents\ccxt\base\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ccxt.base import exchange
  File "C:/Users/samib/Documents\ccxt\base\exchange.py", line 32, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat import backends
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography'
```

Comment: For your second error, It's module error , Try `pip install cryptography`.

Comment: from 1 error message `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+is+required

Answer (score 0):

As your error message says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography'`, I'd try to install [that module](https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/):

```
pip install cryptography
```

Comment: installed cryptography module now getting a new one for requests ;(. guess i will keep installing modules until it works!

Comment: Yeah, you got the spirit ;)

Comment: You are a godsend! installed that requests module and bam its all working! Couldnt thank you enough

Answer (score 0):

to remove that Microsoft Visuallc++ error you wll have to install  Build tools from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16 and later you can do

```
pip install cryptography
```

As you can see it gets installed
[image]

Comment: am currently installing will update soon! many thanks

Comment: If it works accept let me know